# Unable to extract any text from a (visually-)text-filled pdf

Tags: pdf, pdftotext

I've tried most of the various command-line tools, perl's CPAN modules, and a few things besides (Apache's pdf thing, can't remember the name). This is apparently a problem in how the pdf was made, if they've included subfonts with only some of the characters, and didn't map these correctly to the unicode codepoints, pdf software can render the text, but there's no way to meaningfully extract it.

However, there is a non-free command line tool that seems to be able to do so (somehow).

http://www.pdf-tools.com/pdf20/en/products/pdf-manipulation/pdf-extract/

It only works if you use the -s switch, and the documentation has this to say about that:

```
4.2.15 -s Replace Symbolic Characters
    Replace Symbolic Characters -s
    Replace symbolic character from the Unicode custom range (0xF000 to 0xF0FF) with WinAnsi codes (0x00 to 0xFF).

    Note: It is generally recommended to enable this option.
```

This tool is unsuitable for my purposes. It requires a license key, and doesn't even quote a price on the website. I'm working on a free project, and this just makes it impossible.

Is there some way to discern just what strategy they are using to retrieve text that's hidden from every other tool out there? Is there some similar feature in the free tools that I've just missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you did not provide a sample pdf.

Considering the description of the `-s` switch which makes the text extractable, though, it appears as if in the pdf in question *there is a mapping to Unicode* which instead to the regular code points maps glyphs *into the private use range* starting at U+F000 by simply *adding 0xf000* to their actual code point value.

Thus, text extractors believing this mapping should extract unicode characters in the U+F000..U+F0FF range (to do so they might have to be configured to output their result using a sufficiently Unicode encoding, not e.g. ASCII or ANSI).

All you should have to do is take this output and replace U+F0** characters by U+00**.